# How to store data to MariaDB at beforeEach method in Spring boot tests?

Tags: spring, mariadb, spring-boot-test, java-17, junit-jupiter

I cannot write data to db in @beforeEach as lifecycle methods are not transactional. How can I force data to commit? Data is stored in a transaction, but it is executed after the tearDown() method. By the way, I use MariaDB test container.

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = TestConfigurations.Initializer.class,
        classes = {Application.class, TestConfigurations.class})
@Transactional(transactionManager = "transactionManager")
public class SomeTest {

    @Autowired
    private SomeRepository someRepository;

    @Nested
    class SomeNestedClass {


        @BeforeEach
        void setUp() {
            someRepository.saveAll(Fixtures.getSomeEntities());
        }

       @AfterEach
        public void tearDown() {
            someRepository.deleteAll();
        }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your test methods annotated with @Transactional [will be rollback by default by Spring Test](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/transaction/TransactionalTestExecutionListener.html), so you can just initialize your data at the beginning of your test.

Answer (score 0):

try using  [@BeforeTransaction](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/transaction/BeforeTransaction.html)
/ [@AfterTransaction](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/transaction/AfterTransaction.html)